# Show that if $p(X) = X^2 - (a+d)X + (ad-bc)$ and $A $ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $p(A) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, determinant, matrix-equations

> Show that if $p(X) = X^2 - (a+d)X + (ad-bc)$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ then $p(A) = 0$

**My attempted solution:**

$$\begin{align}
p(A) &= \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} - (a+d)\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} + (ad-bc) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}a^2 + bc& ab+ bd\\ca+cd&cb+d^2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}a^2 +da & ab+ db\\ac + dc&ad + d^2\end{bmatrix} + (ad-bc) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}bc-da & 0\\0&cb-ad\end{bmatrix} + (ad-bc) \\
&= -(ad-bc)\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} + (ad-bc)
\end{align}$$

Now, $p(A) = 0$, only if $-(ad-bc)\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = -(ad-bc)$, but that would mean treating a scalar multiplied into an identity matrix as a scalar, and I'm absolutely sure you can't do that.

Is there an error in the question or is there an alternate solution? Or am I wrong in saying that this can't be done, which I highly doubt

Comment: I think that the right interpretation of $p(A)$ is $A^2-(a+d)A + (ad-bc)I$ anyway, so the only way to answer it is the way you're thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should review the definition of what it means to plug a matrix into a polynomial.  If $p(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x^1 + a_0$, then by definition, we have
$$
p(A) = a_nA^n + \cdots + a_1 A^1 + \color{red}{a_0 I}
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Another way to think of it is this: we define $A^0 = I$ for any matrix $A$.  So, $a_0x^0$ becomes $a_0 I$.

Comment: I've never come across this definition before, and I'm currently reading through *Introduction to Linear Algebra by G. Strang*, are there other books that you could recommend that cover this, or any text that covers this?

Comment: Take a closer look.  Can you find the first time he talks about taking a matrix $A$ and plugging it into a polynomial?  It seems bizarre to me that he wouldn't mention it.

Comment: Ah okay I found it, under the section on Vector Spaces, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The notation "$+(ad-bc)$" at the end of the polynomial exactly means "$+(ad-bc)I_2$", $I_2$ denoting the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.